# Where to place the Dandelion datatables configuration on Netbeans

Tags: spring, datatables, dandelion

I am working on a spring mvc project with a dandelion datatables plugin.

I am only able to use it's css/js when I have an internet connection.

What I want is to have a configuration file to set this plugin to [standalone mode](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/configuration/configuration-overloading.html).

My project dirs is similar to [this](http://www.google.com.ph/imgres?imgurl=http://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/image.png&imgrefurl=http://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/struts2/struts-2-netbeans-tutorial.html&h=307&w=320&tbnid=oFKCzOnSBALOTM:&zoom=1&docid=WsGrtrnnwMeJVM&ei=BoJKVaPsB8zhuQS4qIHwCA&tbm=isch&ved=0CEcQMygiMCI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dandelion/datatables` folder is supposed to be placed under the classpath root of your application.

In a [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) project, you would have placed it at:

```
project
|__ src
   |__ main
      |__ resources
         |__ dandelion
            |__ datatables
               |__ datatables.properties
```

Everything placed under the `src/main/resources` folder of your project will be copied under the `WEB-INF/classes` directory and then be read by Dandelion at runtime.

You could do the same manually, but I strongly recommend to use any build tool such as Maven.